# How do I make this query produce the result we need?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables and relevant attributes:

```
Survey:
  SurveyID int,
  SurveyTitle nvarchar(50)

SurveyQuestions
 QuestionId int,
 SurveyId fk from Survey table
 Question nvarchar(100)
 QuestionOrder int (eg: 1,2,3)
AnswerType char(1) (M. for Multiple choice answers like Checkbox, S for single like radiobuttion, T for Free Text


SurveyChoices
 ChoiceId int
 QuestionId int fk from SurveyQuestions
 Choice nvarchar(255) (eg: Choices for each question entered by Admin
 IsCorrect bit (1 for Correct choice, 0 for incorrect choice.

SurveyAnswers
 AnswerId int
 ChoiceId int fk from SurveyChoices
 QuetionId int fk from SurveyQuestions
 ChoiceText nvarchar(2000) (For FreeText)
```

Here is what my need is.

We would like to display a question for EACH survey, followed by User's choice and finally, the correct Answer or Answers.

Users can check more than 1 multiple Choice Answers (checkboxes)

So, the layout should be something like:

```
Question                               Your Choice                     Correct Answer(s)
How many days in a year?                 365                            365
Tom Cruise Starred in 
what movies? Check all that apply       Rain Man                        Rain Man
                                        Risky Business                  Risky Business
                                        Mission Possible                Mission Impossible
```

You can actually see the sql schema on fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/1

Courtesy Steve Ford. Thanks again Steve.

My attempted query is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQ.question, SC.Choice As CorrectAnswer   
                          FROM surveyquestions AS SQ
                          INNER JOIN surveychoices AS SC ON SQ.QuestionID = SC.QuestionID
                          INNER JOIN surveyanswers AS SA ON SA.QuestionID = SQ.QuestionID AND SC.choiceId = SA.choiceId AND SA.username = 'John.Doe'
                          WHERE SQ.SurveyID = 10
```

The questions appear to be correct.

Correct answers are not entirely correct because if more than one choices are correct as in the case of Tom Cruise movies, all of them are not getting displayed.

We would like to display all of the correct answers per question.

Finally, I can't figure out a way to display user's choices.

Your expert assistance is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach a concrete example of what the output should look like? (e.g. John Doe)

Comment: Sure @FabianBigler, I have updated my code above. It doesn't look that clear though but hopefully it will be for you.

That is not entirely the correct output but that's the layout.

Questions are coming out ok. But user's choices need to show ALL choices per question. Same with Correct Answers.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @ChidiOkeh it would help if you added your new survey data to the setup part of the SQLFiddle demo

Comment: @SteveFord, hi. do you entire data?

I am using the exact sample you have on fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think essentially you want to [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/451441/1114171) the correct choices and the given answers seperately then join to the question

something like this

```
WITH CorrectChoices AS
(
  SELECT QuestionID, LEFT(CorrectChoice , LEN(CorrectChoice )-1) AS Choice
  FROM SurveyChoices AS extern
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT Choice + ', '
    FROM SurveyChoices AS intern
    WHERE extern.QuestionID = intern.QuestionID
    AND intern.IsCorrect=1
    ORDER BY Choice
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) pre_trimmed (CorrectChoice)
  GROUP BY QuestionID, CorrectChoice
)
, Answer AS
(
  SELECT QuestionID, UserName, LEFT(CorrectChoice , LEN(CorrectChoice )-1) AS Choice
  FROM SurveyAnswers AS extern
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT Choice + ', '
    FROM SurveyAnswers intern
    INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC ON SC.QuestionId = intern.QuestionID
                               AND SC.ChoiceID = intern.ChoiceID
    WHERE extern.QuestionID = intern.QuestionID
    ORDER BY Choice
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) pre_trimmed (CorrectChoice)
  GROUP BY QuestionID, UserName, CorrectChoice
)

SELECT SQ.Question, CC.Choice, A.Choice Answer, 
       CASE WHEN CC.Choice = A.Choice THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Wrong' END
FROM SurveyQuestions SQ
LEFT JOIN CorrectChoices CC ON CC.QuestionID = SQ.QuestionID
LEFT JOIN Answer A ON A.QuestionID =SQ.QuestionID
WHERE SQ.SurveyID = 10
AND UserName='John Doe'
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/77)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Q.question, C.choice, 
  (SELECT  A1.choice FROM SurveyChoices A1 WHERE A1.choiceid = A.choiceid) AS YourChoice
FROM SurveyQuestions AS Q
left JOIN 
  (SELECT C1.questionid, C1.Choice from SurveyChoices C1 WHERE C1.iscorrect = 1) AS C
   ON Q.questionid = C.questionid
left  JOIN SurveyAnswers A ON A.questionid = Q.questionid
WHERE Q.surveyid = 10  ORDER BY Q.questionorder;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/99

Comment: You two are absolutely amazing. Just to be sure, @TI, which of your columns is the Correct Answer. Is Choice or Answer? Also, I noticed that in checkbox answers, if there are 4 options and 3 of those 4 options are correct, if one correct checkbox is not checked, it should count as wrong answer. That's not happening with your code TI. Barbara, thanks a lot. I am about to test yours now but I see same issue with checkbox with correct answer not checked and not counted. You guys are creatively amazing. THANkS AGAIN

Also Barabara, yours doesn't filter by Username.